# How to convert a doc file to docx with the PHPWord library?

Tags: php, docx, doc, phpword

I want to convert a doc file to a docx file. So many of you advised me to use the PHPWORD library. I used it and tried to convert a doc file to a docx file, but it didn't work as I expected.

**Here is the code I used:**

```
<?php
  require_once 'includes/init.php';
  require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

  $filePath = 'test/example.doc';

  // Creating the new document...
  $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

  $docPath = $filePath;
  $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
  // $document = $phpWord->loadTemplate($docPath);
  $document = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($docPath,'MsDoc');

  $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord,'Word2007');
  $docxPath = 'abc.docx';
  $objWriter->save($docxPath);
  ?>
```

After a lot of research, I discovered in the file CHANGELOG.md of PHPWORD that this function is deprecated.
**here is the proof:**
This image shows deprecation of PHPWORD TemplateProcessor

[image: This image show depreciation PHPWORD TemplateProcessor]

**So I modified my code into this:**

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

  $filePath = 'test/example.doc';

  // Creating the new document...
  // $templateProcessor = new TemplateProcessor($filePath);
  // Creating the new document...
  $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor($filePath);
  $phpWord->save('example.docx');
```

Despite all this does not work, **so what should I do please?**

Comment: _"does not work"_ is not a very good description of a problem. If a customer told you: _"Your webserver doesn't work"_, wouldn't you ask a followup question? Does your code not write the `example.docx`? Is it not really a `docx`? Why use `var_dump()`? Why `die()`?

Comment: I used var_dump to see what happened. But apparently it doesn't work. Can you help me please?

Comment: It's not clear which bit of the deprecation notice you think applies to which part of your code - I don't see any obvious connection. Please be more specific. Also as per [ask], don't include pictures of text, it's unhelpful...there's no reason you couldn't post that as actual text, using a quotation block (see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: @kiko-software It sent me an empty file when I don't use var_dump. What should I do?

Comment: I just modified it.

Comment: OK. Bit 1) the documentation shows that Template is deprecated and replaced by TemplateProcessor. It's not saying that TemplateProcessor is deprecated. 2) your first code doesn't seem to use either of those classes anyway, so it's unclear why you think it's relevant.

Comment: @ADyson How should I write my code to make it clear?